# Condition if else in pug

Tags: javascript, if-statement, pug

I would like to make a simple condition in pug, which is :
If this element exists > Show this element
/ Else > Show a text

There is my code used :

In app.js :

```
  axios
    .get(`${process.env.API_URL}/party/${req.params.id}`)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      let items = null;
      data.items.length === 0 ? items = false : items = true;
      res.render('party', { 
        party: data,
        title: data.name,
        items,
        url: `${process.env.FRONT_URL}:${process.env.PORT}/party/${data._id}` 
    })})
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  ;
});
```

In my .pug file :

```
if items = false
  each item in party.items
    form(method="post" action=`/party/${party._id}/items/${item._id}`)
      p= `${item.name} - ${item.user}`
      button(type="submit") Supprimer
else 
  p Il n'y a pas encore d'objet. Ajoutez-en un !
```

What should I write after my `if`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I got helped and there is the answer:

```
each item in party.items
  form(method="post" action=`/party/${party._id}/items/${item._id}`)
    p= `${item.name} - ${item.user}`
    button(type="submit") Supprimer
if party.items.length === 0 
  p Il n'y a pas encore d'objet. Ajoutez-en un !
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `items = false` will *set* items to `false`, not just check. But even `== false` wouldn't be right, since an unset value is not the same as false.
2. your conditional is backwards; you want to iterate over items only if it's present. So you can just remove the `= false` and use `if items` instead and you should have the logic you want.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for you answer, unfortunately I already tried ```if items``` but it returns my message all the time

Comment: Then maybe it's not null but an empty array. You could try `if items.length > 0`